# Math font to match Simoncini Garamond with unicode-math

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, garamond

I am writing a book using the font Simoncini Garamond, which is the standard font for most Italian publishers. I have the .ttf font for regular text, I am using `XeLaTeX` and `unicode-math` and I tried to match the text font with Garamond Math. Here is my current setting (notice that I must use another math font for sans, this is why I cannot use the `range` option:

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Simoncini Garamond}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{TeX Gyre Heros} %Nimbus Sans
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={5,7,9}]
\setmathfont[version=sansserif]{FiraMath-Regular.otf}
```

However, I am not satisfied with the result (in particular, I don't like the Greek characters of Garamond Math). Here is a sample

[image]

I was just wondering if there is another math font I can use with unicode-math that can be compatible with Garamond (I would be happy of a generic Garamond, not necessarily the Simoncini variant)

Comment: My regards from Sicily :-). You can see that `y` not overlapping the rounded left bracket.

Comment: The `garamond-math`package defines an opentype math font that matches `EB Garamond`.

Comment: One workaround is to `\setmathfontface\vargreek{Some Greek Italic Font}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` and use `\vargreek{\alpha}`, etc.